# iOSアプリで、ログインフォーム作成

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitableview

iOSアプリでログインフォームを作成したいと思っています。
作成したいイメージとしては以下の画面です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この「メールアドレス」と「パスワード」の入力部分をTableViewのContents:Static cellsで作成しようとしています。
(1) UITableViewが元のclassでなければならない
(2) UITableViewでは[ログイン]ボタンを置くことも難しい(Constraintsが設定できない)
(3) TableViewの横幅が縮められない。
(4) そもそもTableViewのContents:Static cellsで作ったほうがいいのかがわからない。

上記の疑問があります。(4)が違う方法がいいということであればその方法をご教示お願いしたく。
(4)がTableViewのContents:Static cellsで作った方がいいということであれば(2)(3)の手法を教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

通常この用途でテーブルビューは使わない

この場合

- UIScrollView

  - UIImageView（ロゴ）
  - UITextField（メールアドレス）
  - UITextField（パスワード）
  - UIButton（ログイン）

のようなビュー構造とする

なお、スクロールビューをスーパービューとするのはキーボードの表示に合わせて表示位置を調整する為である

Comment: 非常にためになります。なお、メールアドレス・パスワードの周りの角丸は背景画像でしょうか？おわかりになればよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `UIView.layer.mask`にマスクレイヤを適用すれば任意の四隅を角丸にすることもできるので背景画像は使用していないと考えられる。ログインボタンは四隅とも丸いので`UIView.layer.cornerRadius`を設定したのだろう